# Javascript size on binary search tree

Tags: javascript, size, binary-search-tree

I have done this is c++ because you can pass in a parameter by reference.  I am having trouble figuring out how to do this in JavaScript.  What do I need to change in my code? My output is 1

```
this.sizeOfBst = function(){
    size = 0;

    return sizeHelper(this.root, size);
}

function sizeHelper(node, size){
    if(node){
        sizeHelper(node.left, size);
        size++;
        sizeHelper(node.right, size);
    }
    return size
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers cannot be passed by reference in Javascript. Instead, have `sizeHelper` return the size and add that size to the total.

```
function sizeHelper(node) {
    if (node) {
        return 1 + sizeHelper(node.left) + sizeHelper(node.right);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then it can be used like

```
this.sizeOfBst = function() {
    return sizeHelper(this.root);
}
```